# Increase and Decrease the values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem. The values from the data array should be increased or decreased every 5 seconds with 0.0001 by following the rule: values should go up for the first minute, then down for the next minute, and so on -

```js
const data = [
    { AUD: "1.5876" }, { BGN: "1.9558" }, { GBP: "0.8527" }, { USD: "1.1820" },
    { UYU: "51.9732" }, { UZS: "12570.5509" }, { VEF: "252746931045.8590" },
    { VND: "27195.9489" }, { VUV: "130.1601" }, { WST: "3.0161" }, { XAG: "0.0449" },
    { XAU: "0.0006" }, { XCD: "3.1944" }, { XDR: "0.8306" },
];
```

This is my code, but i got an infinity loop.

```js
const [currencies, setCurrencies] = useState([]);
let initialTime = true;

useEffect(() => {
    let init = setTimeout(() => {
        initialTime = false;
        console.log('changing the time ' + initialTime);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearTimeout(init)
}, []);

function increase() {
    data.forEach(e => {
        let value = Number(Object.values(e)[0]);
        const key = Object.keys(e)[0];
        setCurrencies({ [key]: value += 0.0001 });
    })
    console.log(currencies);
}

let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (initialTime) {
        increase()
    } else {
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What's that `interval` at the end? If that's in your actual render code, that seems wrong. And it returning something within `setInterval` seems useless?

Comment: So does it stop after two minutes? Based off the description:

**values should go up for the first minute, then down for the next minute, and so on -**

I would have assumed an endless loop was intended?

Comment: I'm just trying to stop setInterval when InitialTime becomes false, but this "if" condition doesn't work. I do not know why.

Comment: @dani because you are returning function that is calling clear, you need to call the clear yourself. instead of `return () => clearInterval(interval);` just `      `clearInterval(interval);` I assume you copied it from the useEffect where return function acts as a cleanup.

Comment: Everytime the `increase` function is called, state is updated and `useEffect` will be invoked. This is the problem.

Comment: @itsmygit this is false, useEffect runs only after the first render in this case.

Comment: @iamwtk, there is no value in the dependency array passed to useEffect so useEffect runs every time state changes.

Comment: @itsmygit that would be case if there wouldn't be any dependency array. If there is one and empty it runs only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So keep track of the time and determine how long it has been and when it hits the length of time, flip it.

```js
let updateTime = Date.now();
const endTime = updateTime + 20000;

let dir = 1;
let value = 1.2357;
const flipTime = 5000;

const timer = setInterval(function () {
  if(Date.now() - updateTime >= flipTime) {
    updateTime = Date.now();
    dir *= -1;
  }
  value += dir * .0001;
  console.log(value.toFixed(4));
  
  // If over end time, stop looping
  if (Date.now() >= endTime) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Side note, setInterval is not 100% accurate so you will see the numbers float around as time runs on.

Comment: Thank you for this, but how can i decrease and increase the values in the data array.

Comment: How is it any different than what you have now? instead of adding the number, you use the variable

Comment: Yes, i did it, but the setInterval doesn't stop.

Comment: Why do you need the interval to stop? The direction flips, no need to stop. You use the `dir` to determine if it is going up or down. No need to create a different function/interval to subtract....

Comment: Updating the values should stop in the 5th minute after opening the page.

Comment: So call clearTimeout when it gets to the 5th minute, just another check.